# How to update several databases with EF 6 on on app start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, data-migration

I am using Entity Framework 6 and do have several databases that needs to be updated on app_start. 
I am having a database for each Customer, so the data structure on each database that I an trying to update is equals, I am using a dynamic connection string in the solution.

Now I want to make sure that the datamodel is updated on all my databases when I deploy a new version. So I have written the code as below, for updating when I Release. But I am getting an exception about "automatic migration is not enabled". If I am setting AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true, it fails with an error, that an object named “MyNewTable” already is in the database, and that is true, it has already been created on a previous update, but it should have known that from the migration-log.

How do I make sure that all my databases is updated without losing data?

Thanks very much in advance

```
            foreach (Customer customer in customerList)
            {
                DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration();
                configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(MakeConnectionString(customer),"System.Data.SqlClient");
                configuration.ContextType = typeof(MyContext);
                configuration.MigrationsAssembly = GetType().Assembly;
                configuration.MigrationsNamespace = GetType().Namespace;

                var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

                migrator.Update();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I wasen't using the Configuration class from the migration folder in the project, I made my own, and that wasen't working. When I tried using the Configuration class from the migratins folder, it worked :-)